# Android, Google maps and changing "required" in uses-permission

Tags: android

I currently have this code in an app that uses Google maps:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="com.example.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />    
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />  
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
```

I have started to wonder though, if I set all these to required="false" the app would presumbly generated a shorter "requires" list when users download the app... Is there any reason not to just set them all to not required?

Currently I do this when loading maps

```
private void setUpMapGoogleIfNeeded() {    
    if (mMapGoogle == null) {
      mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();      
      mSupportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) mFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);           
      mMapGoogle = mSupportMapFragment.getMap();        
      if (mMapGoogle != null) {
        mMapGoogle.setMyLocationEnabled(SharedCode.sharedSupportsGPS(true, thisActivityContext));
      }
    }
```

Does anyone have experience with this? Are the siuttations I have not thought of where setting required = false for above menions can cause errors/exceptions in my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[There is no `android:required` attribute for `<uses-permission>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html) and so it will be ignored. It will not result in "a shorter "requires" list when users download the app".